# How can you tell if or by whom an azure alert was disbaled

Tags: azure

We use Azure Monitor for our application alerts, and I need to see if an alert was disabled at a certain time and by whom.

Any ideas

Comment: Activity logs under Monitor should have all the logs.

Comment: To check Azure Monitor alert was disabled and by whom, you can use Azure Activity Log. The Activity Log provides data about operations that were performed on resources in your account.

Answer (score 0):

> How can you tell if or by whom an azure alert was disbaled?

To check who disabled the Azure alert, follow the steps below.

1. For testing purposes, I set up an alert.

[image]

3.The alert was disabled after it was created.

[image]

Alert has been disabled.

[image]

3. You may check the who disable the Azure Alert by navigating **Azure Monitor > Activity log >check " Create or update metric alert" operations > Change history > properties.enabled**

[image]